# Remote Desktop Connection Login Failed, error-problem connecting

Tags: rhel, login, remote-desktop

I am having a problem remotely logging into my server using remote desktop and `XRDP`.
When attempting to login, I get:

```
Connection Log:
-connecting to sesman ip 127.0.0.1 port 3350
-sesman connect ok
-sending login info to session manager, please wait....
-xrdp_mm_process_login_response: login successful for display 
-started connecting
-conecting to 127.0.0.1 5911 
-tcp connected
-error-problem connecting
```

I had previously been able to connect and use remote desktop to access the server but during one of my previous session last week the remote desktop became unresponsive so I just quit out of it.  Subsequent logins resulted in just one small terminal window in the upper left hand corner, and an X for a cursor, no desktop was present.

So going through and reading things online, I tried to uninstall `XRDP` and `tigervnc-server` and everything seems to be installed correctly but am still not having any success.